# Is it legitimate to simply say "Something lies in that ..." instead of "Something lies in the fact that ..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

I found it inconvenient to repeatedly use "the fact that", and I even feel that the phrase "the fact" may be redundant.

So can I simply say, for instance, "The reason why we choose you lies in that you can do this well" instead of "The reason why we choose you lies in the fact that you can do this well"? Since a sentence preceded by "that" is already an object, there seems to be no need to introduce "the fact"?

Comment: Er, *"The reason why we choose you lies in that you can do this well"* -- That sounds bad to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: "the fact that" is redundant and doesn't serve any purpose here.

You could even make it simpler and more to the point:

> The reason we choose you is that you can do this well.